# How to create a vertical line with an image and text above, which goes through multiple <li>

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble trying to create a vertical line through multiple `<li>`'s, while having some text and an image above it. What I would like to achieve is something like the image below.

[image]

I already found how I can create the vertical line. I found this can be achieved by use the `:after` tag in css on the `<ul>` above. Like for example:

```css
ul:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 0;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 5</li>
</ul>
```

Now I also would like to add some text and an image above this line, like in the example image. Does anyone have an idea how to best achieve this? Or another solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want an image and text as well, then using a pseudo element probably doesn’t make the most sense. I’d just use a normal element to hold the image and the text, position that where needed, and then maybe inside that a pseudo element for the red line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use first `li` for image and text and position it with `position: absolute` so it is aligned with the line. Also you need to add `padding-top` on `ul` and subtract same amount from height of the red line.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
li:not(:first-child) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 80px;
  background: red;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  </li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a look at it now.

Comment: This is working perfectly! Thanks! Is it also possible to add another line with image and text next to it a bit further to the right?

Comment: Sure you can use other pseudo element like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1565/

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you use the `::before` (or `::after`) pseudo element on each `<li>` for the line so you can save the `<ul>` pseudo elements for the text and image, like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
ul::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
ul::after {
  content: "Here's some text";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  left: 5px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One
  <li>Two
  <li>Three
  <li>Four
</ul>
```

And then replace `background` in `ul::before` with an image... I can't think of another workaround without using extra markup or javascript

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: 1;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
}
.header img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
.header p {
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
}
.header p:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: tomato;
  top: 0;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-150-80-3.jpg"><p>some text</p>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
  <li>Test 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```